# Setting custom font color for XSSFWorkbook in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm having a little trouble with setting a custom font color for an `XSSFWorkbook` from `Apache POI`. When I do:

```
    yellow = workbook.createCellStyle();
    Font whiteFont = workbook.createFont();
    whiteFont.setColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(255, 255, 255)).getIndexed());
    yellow.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(yellowRGB));
    yellow.setFillPattern(XSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    yellow.setFont(whiteFont);
```

The font stays black, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do `whiteFont.setColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(255,255,255)));`

However, there is a [bug in Apache POI](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51236), where it is switching black and white. It looks like they put a 'fix' in [XSSFColor.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.java) (look at XSSFColor.correctRGB()) to correct for a problem in Excel.  It's likely that Excel was fixed, but Apache POI wasn't updated.

Instead you can do: `whiteFont.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index)`
or `whiteFont.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.index);` (this is deprecated)

or if you do `whiteFont.setColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(255,255,254)));` it'll be really close to white.

Comment: But the problem is I have to use `getIndexed()` because `Font.setColor(short)` uses `short` as the parameter. Also, the method doesn't work at all because I thought maybe it was just for White but when I did `whiteFont.setColor(new XSSFColor(new Color(234, 17, 156)).getIndexed());`, it still stayed Black

Comment: There's some problem with getIndexed(), it's likely a problem in CTColor, which is what XSSFColor is using under the hood.  What version of POI are you using?  You can still do `whiteFont.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index)` or `whiteFont.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.index);`

Comment: What is the type of your workbook?  What is the full type for the Font class that you are using?  (Which package?)

Comment: XSSFWorkbook.createFont() returns an XSSFFont.   You should use that.

Comment: I'm using `POI` v3.12, the type of workbook is a .xlsx file so I'm using the `XSSFWorkbook` class, and I was using `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font` for the font class until you told me to switch to `XSSFFont` (`org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont`). However, I switched to `XSSFFont` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to use getIndexed() if you use XSSFFont.  With XSSFFont you can now use any of the solutions I described in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
XSSFFont font = (XSSFFont) wb.createFont();
font.setColor(new XSSFColor( Color.decode("#7CFC00")));
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue